# how to set image url in wordpress text editor

Tags: wordpress, image, url, text-editor

I insert image in a post via text editor. The full path is the image is

```
    http://74.52.17.77/~printing/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/march19coupon1-300x172.png
```

But after moving the wordpress to the main website this url should be this

```
    http://74.52.17.77/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/march19coupon1-300x172.png
```

Then I have to change this in all the posts. :(

Is there any way to set this url so i do not need to change this every time.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023056/change-wordpress-image-url/18023100

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reach that goal trough a SQL sentence, which will update all those old urls...