# Change Wordpress Image URL

Tags: image, wordpress, path, directory

On my wordpress site all my images are showing up as broken links. They are also showing up as broken links in the media gallery in the wordpress backend.

I inspected the images using Google chrome and saw that they all show up like this:

```
<img src="http://firouzeh.co.uk/frouzeh/frouzeh/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/04/Granulated-Persepolis-Ring-230x160.jpg">
```

there is a duplication of a file name in the path and to get the images to work I need the path to look like this:

```
<img src="http://firouzeh.co.uk/frouzeh/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/04/Granulated-Persepolis-Ring-230x160.jpg">
```

I have searched through the database and cannot find where to change the path to my images, specifically I think there must be a field somewhere that is directing everything to www.firouzeh.co.uk/frouzeh where it should just be sending it to www.firouzeh.co.uk.

Does anyone know where to change the path?

Comment: Under the settings do you have your wordpress and Site address set correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your URL settings are correct under Settings > General, then you could try using a Search and Replace plugin to update every occurrence in your database.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Search for firouzeh.co.uk/frouzeh/frouzeh
Replace it with firouzeh.co.uk/frouzeh

Back up your site first :)

If you did just move your site from another location, I suggest using the Duplicator plugin, which handles all of the replacing.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: Hi Kenny, thanks for the link to search & replace - that worked like a charm for me. will keep duplicator in mind for future migrations.

Comment: Np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Use the same solution I wrote for here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18023214/1946078

It is as follows:

When you move a Wordpress install, you need to also edit two fields in the database. Run this against your database in order to find the values that need to be edited:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE option_name IN('siteurl', 'home');
```

If database access is not an option, another way to do this is by editing your wp-config.php file to include the following two lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yoursite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yoursite.com');
```

Straight from http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

> 1. The "Home" setting is the address you want people to type in their browser to reach your WordPress blog.
> 2. The "Site URL" setting is the address where your WordPress core files reside.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kimberly. I should have mentioned this in the question, I'm using WP multisite with 2 sites. I have checked the wp_options file in the database for both sites and for the one in question the 'siteurl' and 'home' settings are both https://firouzeh.co.uk/ -so as would be expected. Are there any other places in the DB to look? Also to confirm, I have checked the wp_config.php file and I'm definitely looking at the right database (I have a couple of different versions in phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 2):

I used the solution from [this article](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-change-wordpress-urls-in-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin):

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'oldurl.com','newurl.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'oldurl.com','newurl.com');
```

After changing the `Site URL` and `WP home` in the admin panel.

Comment: Very good summary of all actions that needs to be performed in case of host or IP or DNS change.